# Insert/Translate a Column from Another Table?

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a single table of data that contains a bunch of information that I'm trying to display. A total of 3057 records, so I would expect my final query to spit back 3057 records.

Essentially, I want to be able to create a `SELECT` statement, that allows me to include a column on the original table, translating that particular column (basically, the row has an ID, but that same table also can translate the ID to a Public name).

It's easy to do a basic join, and add the column, based on a specific filter/search:

```
DefView = '(None)' AND DefType = 'DefPublicName' -- 250 records
```

This result gives me all of the records that have a name that can be translated. So now I can add that column to my initial `SELECT` and be on my way.

The problem is my record count is entirely off now. I believe it's missing the items that it DIDN'T find when I did the `JOIN`. I get 2342 records, most likely because there is data that isn't bound when we create the `JOIN ON` clause.

Another way to say this, I believe, is that we're only adding the "valid" PublicTitle columns that currently exist. So if we have rows without this information, it essentially is excluded.

Whereas the functionality I want, is to include it, and if we don't have a PublicTitle, it can be `NULL`/empty.

Since I knew we're missing records, I figured a `UNION` would help bring the missing ones back. Just having trouble really getting the exact query to end up with the total 3057 rows when it's all said and done.

```
SELECT
    TD.RecID,
    TD2.DefName AS PublicTitle,
    TD.DefType,
    TD.DefID,
    TD.DefName,
    TD.DefView,
    TD.DefOwner
FROM DefinitionTable AS TD --3057
JOIN DefinitionTable TD2 ON TD.DefOwner = TD2.DefID -- 4213
WHERE TD2.DefView = '(None)' AND TD2.DefType = 'DefPublicName' --2342.
UNION (SELECT   TD3.RecID,
    '' AS PublicTitle,
    TD3.DefType,
    TD3.DefID,
    TD3.DefName,
    TD3.DefView,
    TD3.DefOwner FROM DefinitionTable TD3 WHERE TD3.DefView != '(None)' AND TD3.DefType != 'DefPublicName') --2713
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure I got it doing this:

```
Select
(SELECT TOP 1 DefName As PublicTitle From DefinitionTable  TD1 Where TD1.DefID = TD2.DefOwner AND TD1.DefView = '(None)') As PublicTitle
, * From DefinitionTable TD2
```